# Joomla 3 - Virtuemart - Virtuemar product module

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0, virtuemart

I'm using Joomla 3 and Virtuemart 3.0.18.

I'm building a website to show products of my store. So, I created 2 modules in the same type: mod_virtuemart_product. I need one of them display my newest products and other display featured products.

My problem is my website just display one of them in a same page.

Please help me! Thank you so much!

Update:

In my template, I load those modules using  like this:

```
<?php if ($this->countModules('modpro')) : ?>
    <div class="modpro">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="modpro" style="xhtml" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ($this->countModules('modnew')) : ?>
    <div class="modnew">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="modnew" style="xhtml" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I tried setting them in the same position, but it doesn't work.

I disabled one of them, other were be renderred. I set them on difference pages, them were be renderred.

Comment: We need some code to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone who viewed this question.

I has found the reason of my issue. In the sortSearchListQuery() function of the VirtueMartModelProduct class, I found these code line:

```
if(self::$_alreadyLoadedIds){
    $where[] = ' p.`virtuemart_product_id`!='.implode(' AND p.`virtuemart_product_id`!=',self::$_alreadyLoadedIds).' ';
    //$where[] = ' p.`virtuemart_product_id` NOT IN ('.implode(',',self::$_alreadyLoadedIds).') ';
}
```

It prevent my second module from loading the same products again.

So, thank you again!